# Unexpected include error in c++, c1xx trying to open file from non-existent directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working in visual studio 2022 with c++. I am trying to include a header file `include.h` from my file `application.cpp`.

The structure of my project is as follows:

```
src:
    application.cpp
    indexBuffer.h
    indexBuffer.cpp
```

It was temporarily structured like this however:

```
src:
    graphics:
        indexBuffer.h
        indexBuffer.cpp

    application.cpp
```

I now get the build error:

```
1>indexBuffer.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'src\graphics\indexBuffer.cpp': No such file or directory
```

The graphics folder doesn't exist anymore, and is no longer included in my solution include.

In `application.cpp` I have the line `#include "indexBuffer.h"`

I'm expecting it to run with no build errors, as this should just be a typical include from the same directory.

Why is it still trying to open `graphics\indexBuffer.cpp` ?

Is there any way to "tell" the compiler that this folder doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: `Why is it still trying to open graphics\indexBuffer.cpp` Because you have moved the file with the File Explorer. Now you should remove it from the Visual Studio project and add the file at the new location.

Comment: You can remove it from "Solution Explorer" and readd it in the correct place. You could also edit the project file in a text editor (make a backup first). The project file is xml.

Comment: @drescherjm how do i read it in the correct place?

Comment: Right click on the project in "Solution Explorer" then click Add->Existing Item or Press `Shift+Alt+A`

Comment: @drescherjm Did this, still get the same error. Error list says ```Two or more files with the name of indexBuffer.cpp will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are src\graphics\indexBuffer.cpp, src\indexBuffer.cpp. ```

Comment: Did you remove the file from "Solution Explorer" first? I expect you just added it without removing it first.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, selected the file in the solution explorer and clicked "remove"

Comment: That should be all that you need to do. You may want to close Visual Studio. Make a backup of the project file. Then look at it in a text editor searching for `indexBuffer.cpp`. A project file will have a `.vcxproj` extension and its an xml file so its text.

Comment: @drescherjm Removing references to the ```graphics``` folder from the ```.vcxproj``` files removed all errors and it's now building successfully. Thanks for the help.